# globstar set in terminal not propagating to script

Tags: bash, shell, shopt

I need to build a library with the build.sh provided with the source.  It contains a globstar path (`src/**/*.java`). I enabled globstar with `shopt -s globstar` and all works great from terminal but from bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls **/*.java
```

I get the following error:

```
ls: cannot access **/*.java: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put

```
shopt -s globstar
```

into the script as well.

Comment: Thanks. This + running file with bash instead of sh did the trick.